# How to permanently remove all commits after a certain commit to reduce disk space?

Tags: git

For testing purpose, I need a reduced linux kernel git repo which contains less commits and takes less disk space.  For example, let's say I need to permanently remove all commits after [v3.2](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/805a6af8dba5dfdd35ec35dc52ec0122400b2610), I tried the following commands to remove all commits in master after 805a6a:

```
git reset --hard 805a6af8dba5dfdd35ec35dc52ec0122400b2610
git gc --aggressive --purne=all
```

Before running the commands, the repo takes 2.7G disk space.  After running the commands, the repo takes 2.0G disk space, but I think it can take even less disk space because no commit seems to have been truly removed: before and after running commands, the outputs of "git rev-list --all --count" are both 949352.

Any idea?  How to permanently remove commits after 805a6a so that they take no disk space?

Comment: A tag is a commit name so it would have been sufficient to `git reset --hard v3.2`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

> For testing purpose, I need a reduced linux kernel git repo which contains less commits and takes less disk space.

You can achieve that by doing a sort of inverted [shallow clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_shallow_repository) that includes the history up to a specific tag. You can do that with the [`--branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---branchltnamegt) and [`--single-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---no-single-branch) options of [`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone). For example:

```
git clone https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git --single-branch --branch v3.2
```

Note that the cloned repo will be in a [detached HEAD](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefdetachedHEADadetachedHEAD) state (since `HEAD` will be pointing to a tag rather than a branch), so you'll have to create a branch yourself before doing any work.

Comment: `--branch` alone only changes what you check out; it doesn't limit what gets cloned.  It would be necessary to use `--single-branch` as well.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Correct. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this isn't doing what you want is that `gc` will only remove commits if *nothing* is referencing them.  That could mean other branches from which the commit is reachable.  It could mean tags.  It most certainly means your reflogs.

Convincing git to drop committed data is deliberately not so easy.  It can be done, but for a repo the size of the linux kernel's, I don't think it's a reasonable task.

Why not just clone the part you need.  You can give a `--branch` option to specify the version you want, a `--single-branch` option to copy only the history leading up to that version, and possibly even a `--depth` option (or other shallowing options) to limit how much history you copy.